# How to add dynamic jquery button?

Tags: jquery-ui, button

I have a table where I use jquery to add and delet rows. I also use jquery ui to render buttons.

When I add a new row, I also add a button in a cell, but this one is not rendered.

```
var tdata = "<tr>";
tdata += "<td align=\"right\">my data</td>";
tdata += "<td align=\"left\">";
tdata += "<button class=\"delete\">delete</button>";
tdata += "</td>";
tdata += "</tr>";

jQuery('#mytable > tbody:last').append(tdata);
```

Any idea, how to solve this ?

thx

### UPDATE 1

Looks like I forgot to post one important detail :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
jQuery('button.delete').button();
}
```

This works after loading the page but not for the new rows.

Comment: Btw, this also is a problem if I add a click function like ' jQuery('button.delete').click(function() 
 {return false;}); I mean it works when I do this on $(document).ready() but not for the dynamic added buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ready() function, you are creating jquery-ui styled buttons, but they will only apply to currently existing buttons.

Therefore, dynamically added buttons won't have this applied to them, so you'll have to modify your addRow function to apply the button() call in relation to the newly created markup.

Like this:

```
var tdata = "<tr>";
tdata += "<td align=\"right\">my data</td>";
tdata += "<td align=\"left\">";
tdata += "<button class=\"delete\">delete</button>";
tdata += "</td>";
tdata += "</tr>";
var tdataElement = jQuery(tdata);
jQuery('button.delete',tdataElement).button();
jQuery('#mytable > tbody:last').append(tdataElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and I didn't found any problems, but I changed the tag  with the tag

This is my piece of code
In the section head

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fooBtn').bind('click', function(event) {
            addRow();
    });
    });
 </script>
```

input[type=button].delete {
        color: red 
`  }

function addRow is your code

```
function addRow(){
    var tdata = "<tr>"; 
    tdata += "<td align=\"right\">my data</td>"; 
    tdata += "<td align=\"left\">"; 
    tdata += "<input type=\"button\" class=\"delete\" value=\"delete\">"; 
    tdata += "</td>"; 
    tdata += "</tr>"; 
    jQuery('#mytable > tbody:last').append(tdata); 
}
```

In the section body

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            my data
        </td>
        <td align="left">

            <input type="button" class="delete" value="delete"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="button" id="fooBtn" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only delete" value="Add Row" />
```

Try and give me a feedback
D.

For handler click events you have to change this piece of code

var tdataElement = jQuery(tdata);

```
 var bt = tdataElement.find(":button");
  bt.button();
  bt.click(function() {
      alert('Handler for .click() called.');
  });
  jQuery('#mytable > tbody:last').append(tdataElement);
```

Comment: Looks like I missed something important in my post... please have a look

Answer (score 0):

To apply the theme you need to find the button, and then apply the style

```
tdataElement.find(":button").button();
jQuery('#mytable > tbody:last').append(tdataElement);
```