# Dynamic Button not refreshing CSS properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

First time posting = )
I have been searching for a little while and have tried many ('refresh').trigger , ('create') and markup answers other members have suggested or I have seen on other posts. I am pretty new to JS JQM but I am having troubles having my dynamically added buttons viewed with the CSS properties. I have tried other solutions posted on similar questions such as:
[How to add dynamic jquery button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153526/how-to-add-dynamic-jquery-button)
[Jquery Dynamically generated buttons no css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093292/jquery-dynamically-generated-buttons-no-css)
A few other posts too.

Sorry in advance if already answered, I could not find a solution.

Here is my code:
The Reason I made the button a variable was because of another form post suggested it then refreshing that way...

```
$( '#csvButton' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $('#viewData').empty();
    $('#testView').empty();
        $.ajax( {
            url: 'xhr/data.csv',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text',
            success:function ( result ) {
            //console.log(result);
            var lines = result.split("\n");
            //console.log(lines);
            var dataRow = lines[0];
            var dataCol = dataRow.split(",");
            for (var lineNum = 1; lineNum < lines.length; lineNum++) {
                var row = lines[lineNum];
                var columns = row.split(",");
                    var thisButton = $("<a>").attr("href", "#").attr("data-role", "button").attr("data-theme", columns[1]).attr("data-icon", columns[2]).text(columns[0]);
                thisButton.appendTo('#testView');
                $('<ul>' + '<li><b>' + dataCol[0] + " " + columns[0] + '</b></li>' +
                    '<li>'+ dataCol[1] + " " + columns[1] + '</li>' +
                    '<li>'+ dataCol[2] + " " + columns[2] + '</li>' + '</ul>'
                ).appendTo('#testView');
        }   
            }
        });
    });
return false;
});
```

I am having trouble with thisButton displaying properly with CSS properties. I am made it a link with data-role="button" and trying it as a 
my CSV has button name "Settings", button theme  "a", and button icon "gear" data.
Any help would be great. #testView was a temp  I created to test ideas to get CSS properties to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well you're working on dynamic buttons so it seems it would be better if you set css to a class and then add class to button dynamicaly.
Try add class to your css code with parameters you need and then in your code put somewhere

```
$("#testView").addClass("name of your class");
```

I'm sorry but i can test this solution right away so i'm not sure if its working as you wish. 
Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove or put CSS properties with this:

E.g.:

```
 $("#testView").class('display', 'none');
```

Look at this [Porperty CSS documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)